# Caliburn Micro - how to expose properties, solve binding issues in usercontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am learning MVVM using Caliburn Micro. I have two views: `ShellView`(Main window) and `PersonView`(UserControl). The ShellView gets bound properly to the ShellViewModel with no problem, but it doesn't seem to properly bind the usercontrol to its associated ViewModel.

I have a property `MyPerson` initialized in `ShellViewModel` that matches the `x:Name` of the control in the `ShellView`, by CM convention it should bind the DataContext to the PersonViewModel (I got this approach from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291466/caliburn-micro-user-control-data-context)), but it doesn't. The Binding label shows `CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.ShellViewModel`.

I explicitly added the DataContext to the ViewModel in the UserControl to fix this.

> DataContext="CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel"

I verified it with the Binding Label as it shows `CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel`, but I have the following issues now:

1. The properties and Actions in the ViewModel are not bound. The initialized MyPerson's values are not reflected and the button `SayMyName` doesnt do anything.
2. The properties are not exposed to the main window. I ultimately want to bind the FirstName and LastName props of PersonView control to other controls in the Shell View.

How do I fix these? Following are the code associated.

**ShellView.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="CMTestUserControlMVVM.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMTestUserControlMVVM.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800"
    >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Width="100" x:Name="DoSomething" Content="Do Something"/>

    <local:PersonView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyPerson" 
                      Width="350" Height="100"
                      />

    <Label Content="{Binding}" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

**Associated ViewModel**:

```
namespace CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Screen
    {
        private PersonViewModel model;

        public PersonViewModel MyPerson
        {
            get { return model; }
            set 
            { 
                model = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyPerson);
            }
        }

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            MyPerson = new PersonViewModel()
            {
                FirstName = "Shameel",
                LastName = "Mohammed"
            };
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Doing Something");
        }
    }
}
```

**PersonView.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMTestUserControlMVVM.Views.PersonView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMTestUserControlMVVM.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         DataContext="CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel"
         >
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock x:Name="FirstName"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LastName"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SayMyName" Content="Say My Name!"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding}"/>
</Grid>
```

**Associated ViewModel**:

```
namespace CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string _firstName;

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set 
            { 
                _firstName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstName);
            }
        }

        private string _lastName;

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set 
            { 
                _lastName = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LastName);
            }
        }

        public void SayMyName()
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Hi {FirstName} {LastName}!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that `DataContext="CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel"` only assigns the string literal "CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel" to the DataContext property. Remove that assignment and try `<local:PersonView DataContext="{Binding MyPerson}" .../>`. A UserControl should generally never explicitly set its own DataContext.

Comment: @Clemens tried, no luck. Even though the label shows CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel, properties and actions are not bound. Tried adding cm:Bind.Model="CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel" as well, same behavior

Comment: @Clemens should I add something in the PersonView ctor to load up the viewmodel?

Comment: What do you expect when you write `Content="{Binding}"` without any source property? Maybe you wanted to write `<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>` and similar for other properties.

Comment: @Clemens that Binding in label content (both in `shellview` and `usercontrol`) is to verify the bound viewmodel during runtime, it doesn't serve any other purpose other than debugging. I have textblocks for `FirstName` and `LastName` in the stackpanel.

Comment: But obviously without any Bindings. As already said, there should be `Text="{Binding FirstName}"` etc.

Comment: `Text="{Binding FirstName}"` is not how you do things in Caliburn.Micro.I guess `Content="{Binding}"` is just temporary to be able to see what the current `DataContext` is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `DataContext="CMTestUserControlMVVM.ViewModels.PersonViewModel"` as this sets the `DataContext` to a `string` literal which makes no sense.
2. Replace the `UserControl` with a `ContentControl` in ShellView.xaml:

   ```
   <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MyPerson" 
                   Width="350" Height="100" />
   ```

Comment: This did the trick! But how do I set the properties in xaml?

Comment: What properties?